# How to enter information in one cell based on text in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I would like to enter information in a cell based on the text contained in a different cell. Specifically, if a cell in column A contains text that includes "insurance," "retirement," or "401K," then I want to place an "x" in its respective cell in Column B. If not, then cell B1 should be empty. The text needs to be contained within the cell, but does not need to be the exact text. E.g., an "x" would still be placed in the column next to "life insurance" or "insurance," "whole life insurance," etc.

E.g.,

```
Column A        Column B
Life Insurance  x
Securities
Retirement      x
```

I tried to use the following formula, but am getting an error message when I do so:

```
IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("insurance",A1,"retirement",A1, "401K",A1)),"x", "")
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula should help:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("Insurance",A1)),ISNUMBER(FIND("Retirement",A1)),ISNUMBER(FIND("401K",A1))),"x","")
```

EDIT:

I came up with an array formula that I like a little better. Hope this helps:

```
=IF(COUNT(MATCH({"*Insurance*","*Retirement*","*401K*"},A1,0))>0,"x","")
```

This will require pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER after putting it in the cell because it's an array formula.

Comment: I was unable to get the edited version to work. It says, "False" even when one of the words is in the cell. However, your first version works great. How come you like the second attempt better?

Comment: Interesting. I'll try to figure out why that's the case. I liked it better because it was more concise. Good luck with your workbook. I'll come back and post if I can reproduce the `FALSE`s and correct the error.

Comment: Did you copy the formula verbatim? My best guess would be that the last `,""` wasn't included. If that were the case, you would get the `FALSE` result when one of the words was not there.

Comment: You're right, something went awry with the copy/paste. Your revised version works great, too. Thank you.